# Google font special character displayed correctly on PC but not in HTML?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I am using a Google font "Kameron". I downloaded it from [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com)

It displays special characters such as "š" **correctly** in Photoshop, and also in a .PDF file viewed in browser. So, the font obviously supports these characters and the browser is able to render them.

However, when used in a HTML Web Page and viewed in browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge) it doesn't display the special character, instead it replaces the character with a default 'serif' font.

I am running the website locally.
I've included the font using Google's standard `<link>` embed.
I've also tried downloading it, converting it to a web font, hosting it locally and importing it using `@font-face` in CSS, but that didn't help.

I've tried searching but couldn't find anything relevant to this specific situation. I'm sorry if the answer is obvious or something but I'm not seeing it. Can you help?

```css
h2, p { font-family: 'Kameron', serif;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kameron:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <h2>Tešting</h2>
```

Comment: Have you tried set the html encoding as utf-8?

Comment: Yes, its set:  `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: The TTF file doesn't contain the glyph for š. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwT8i.png Not sure how Photoshop manages to show it; maybe it chose a font that was more similar to Kameron than the one the browser chose?

Comment: @MrLister No, see: [https://i.imgur.com/r5L9vwu.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/r5L9vwu.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Since the TTF file doesn't contain a `š` glyph, you can use the NFD form, the combined glyphs `s` and `̌`, or, `š`.
My guess is that's how Photoshop does it.
To see the differences between the NFC and NFD forms, see here:

```css
   div {font:72px 'Kameron';}
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kameron:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
   
<div>NFC: smje&#x0161;ten</div>
<div>NFD: smje&#x0073;&#x030C;ten</div>
```

Disclaimer: doesn't work as well as could be hoped in all browsers. This is what I was going for:

[image]

Comment: Interesting and a nice try, but yeah, it doesn't appear to work very well in most browsers.

Comment: I have similar problem with [Cinzel Decorative](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cinzel+Decorative?query=cinz&preview.text=%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99&preview.text_type=custom) and your option doesn't look good, but in [preview on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cinzel+Decorative?query=cinz&preview.text=%C4%9B%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%99&preview.text_type=custom) it works perfectly.

Comment: OK, maybe the font doesn't have the character and some software can combine different glyphs to get one. But I have a problem with the infinity symbol `∞`. "Noto Serif" font apparently does have it, as Google Fonts preview displays the symbol all right (although the font-family is set to `Noto Serif script=latin rev=2` in CSS). However, if I add the character into a simple HTML and open it in a browser (tried both Chrome and Firefox on Linux, page on a remote server), the browser selects a local alternative font (DejaVu Serif by default, or, say, Arial, if I've set it as the fallback in CSS).

Comment: I also downloaded "Noto Serif" font and opened it in `gucharmap`, and it displays the character all right, so the glyph should be there.